# Is there a tutorial on C++ programming in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

Can anyone link me to a decent c++ tutorial that's actually currently in date? Almost everything I find applies to 2005 and the code examples are riddled with errors which won't run in my 2008 version of the visual compiler.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking for a C++ tutorial, or a tutorial for programming Windows with C++? The C++ standard hasn't changed since 2005, so I assume the latter.

Comment: thanks to J.F.Sebastian for claifying my title for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *Accelerated C++* is a good start to learn C++.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition Introdution: [Introduction to Visual C++ 2008 Express (Video)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb964629.aspx). You will find a good book-list about Standard C++ here: http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/fncpp/Resources#books (that's the website of the ##c++ irc channel on irc.freenode.org). For an explanation of the difference between C++ and Visual C++ you can read this: http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/#vc.

Answer (score 1):

C++ hasen't changed much over the years code from i.e. www.vtc.com 's video-tutorials still applies and those are made ~2000.

But if you are specificly looking for Visual C++, then you might need newer Tutorials, but if you want to learn C++, start off small and not with Visual C++.

Answer (score 0):

Visual C++® 2008: How to Program, Second Edition

came up on safari a little while ago, looks quite good for an introduction to visual studio and C++